# Javascript brackets

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that looks like this;

```
var x(10);
var i = 3;
x(i) = 7
document.write("The stored value is " + x(3) +"
```

This is a piece of code in the book I am reading from, but they don't explain what the brackets mean? Does x(10) mean that x is 10? That wouldn't make sense. Same with x(i), what does that even mean? I don't understand what output I would get from this! I want to understand it before I move on to the next section so I'm not confused. I'm thinking the output would be 7, but I still would like to understand the meaning behind the brackets.

Comment: what is the context of this use

Comment: This is just an example in the book, teaching us about variables and things. They don't have a program from this section of code, it's just very basic introductory Javascript and they haven't explained what the brackets mean when placed next to a variable. Thanks.

Comment: And what book is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always try the below

```
var x = [10]; // Declare an array with a single element, which is 10
var i = 3; // Declare another variable

x[i] = 7; 
/* Assign a value to index 3 of the array. Index 0 is occupied by 10. So indices 1 and 2 will be undefined. JS arrays grow automatically when new elements are added. */ 

document.write("The stored value is " + x[3]); // Print the value in the 3rd index of the array, which you set in the last line.
```

This will execute in your browser console.

Comment: AHHH it's an array! That's where I was confused. Thank you! So the output would indeed be 7 since that is the 3rd element?

Comment: @user3247128 Yes. That is it.

Comment: Thank you! :) Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`var x(10);` is trying to define a variable whose name is `x(10)` and value is `undefined`.

However, `x(10)` is an illegal javascript variable name. Your snippet would not run on Chrome console.

A javascript variable name validator: https://mothereff.in/js-variables

Reference:　https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

Answer (score 0):

The example tells that your are reading Arrays. Below is the explanation.

```
var x(10);
```

An array is defined with size 10

```
var i = 3;
x(i) = 7;
```

The 4th element of the array is assigned a value of 7. The first element count always starts from 0

```
document.write("The stored value is " + x(3) +"
```

document.write method is used to print the output. BTW, your syntax is wrong, you missed the `;` on the third line.

Comment: @epascarello - Right said. Rather square brackets are used.